# Declaring a parameter in html and receiving it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, alert

My js function goes like this:

```
function tester (message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

And in the markup I have:

```
<a href="#" onclick="tester(text to show);">Link</a>
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't sell yourself short by saying noob like that (I edited the question). Sometimes things aren't so intuitive in programming, and everybody has had to deal with doubts like that at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text to show` is not a string unless you wrap it with quotes, either single or double.

Like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="tester('text to show');">Link</a>
```

Notice that you can't use the same kind of quote for both the Javascript code and the HTML.

Your code is probably giving errors. Check the console when the code doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: When i insert a randon number like this
`<a href="#" onclick="tester(123);">link</a>`
it works fine! but when i use a php variable it dont `<?php $txt='Text to show'; echo'<a href="#" onclick="tester('.$txt.');">link</a>'; ?>` why?

Comment: Numbers work because the `alert` function can take numbers as parameters. As for PHP code, the variable itself should contain the quotes.

Comment: Hell yeah!!, it works with `<?php $txt = "'text to show'"; echo'<a href="#" onclick="tester('.$txt.');">link</a>'; ?>` Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. All you have to do is wrap text to show in quotes, like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="tester('text to show');">Link</a>
```

What's happening here is that you have an `<a>` tag with two attributes, `href` and `onclick`. In the `href` you write the URL that the link points to. In the `onclick` attribute, you write Javascript. The Javascript here is:

```
tester('text to show');
```

which runs a function called `tester`, passing it the string `'text to show'`. Your original code had Javascript like this:

```
tester(text to show);
```

which results in a Syntax Error. As an aside, if you had Javascript like this:

```
tester(text);
```

it would have looked for a *variable* named `text`, and if this variable was defined, you would get an alert with that text.

One more thing: when you include text inside HTML attributes, like you did here, you should be careful not to use the same quotes you used to enclose the attribute. That is why we used single quotes. Suppose you wanted to use double-quotes or other fancy characters, such as the © symbol ... then you replace them with their "HTML-escaped" value, in this case `&copy;`. [Click here for some common values.](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)

Comment: Thanks Gregory.
when i put in the html: `onclick="tester(32423);"` a randon number for example its works!! but it dont when i put there a php variable like this

`<?php $txt='Text to show'; echo'<a href="#" onclick="tester('.$txt.');">link</a>'; ?>`

it doesn't work, why?

Comment: Try to imagine in your head what the PHP would do. The final output would look like

<a href="#" onclick="tester(Text to show);"> which causes the problem I described above.